# Swift UI padding on Navigation "back" button

Tags: swiftui, navigation, padding

How do I adjust the padding of a Swift UI "back" navigation button? i.e. the blue "Navigation" text in the image below (Image contributed by someone else on a different question). I want to add more space between the text and the leading edge of the screen.

[image]

Comment: Looks like my screenshot :) but anyway, you're trying to make the "Navigation" text shifted more right? Would be pretty hard to do. In the case of Apple's UI it's best to go along with what they designed. If you want to customize anything, it's better to make your own components.

Comment: that's what I was afraid of haha

Comment: you can make your own "back" button. In that case you can use the trick/hack 
and put some blank spaces in front of the chevron.

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom appearance for this purpose configured in the `init` of view holding `NavigationView`.

Here is a demo (with big offset for better visibility). Prepared with Xcode 13 / iOS 15.

```
init() {
    let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    appearance.backButtonAppearance.normal.titlePositionAdjustment = 
        UIOffset(horizontal: 40, vertical: 0)

    UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
}
```

[image]

Comment: that does not move the button unfortunately, only the text